# Can I run shell script together with application?

Tags: bash, scripts, background-process

I wrote small script to automatically delete Chrome cache after I close it:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    if [[ $(pgrep -l chrome) ]]; then
        sleep 20
    else
        rm -rf ~/.cache/google-chrome/Default/Cache/*
        rm -rf ~/.cache/google-chrome/Default/"Media Cache"/*
        notify-send "CCD" "Cache deleted!"
        break    
fi
done
```

Now I don't want to run this script manually everytime, I want it to run in background automatically when I launch Chrome. I tried to edit Chrome quicklist with Ubuntu Tweak:
[image]

But as I expected, it didn't work. So, is there any other way to do it?

Comment: If you start Chrome, then manually run the script from the terminal, does it function as expected?

Comment: Yes, I tested it and it works as it should

Comment: It sounds like it may be executing too fast to detect the Chrome process.  Perhaps add a sleep function to the script?  Something like a `sleep 5` to make it pause for 5 seconds before continuing to execute?  This should give Chrome time to load.

Comment: Also, the answer below has a good point, maybe use a complete path to your script http://askubuntu.com/a/850804/606721

Comment: Where exactly should I add a sleep function? I already have one in.

Comment: Prior to the `while true`. Basically, your script is detecting Chrome, then sleeping. We need it to sleep first, *then* detect Chrome.

Comment: In the case of chrome, I'd prefer a wrapper over a constantly running script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add full path to your script into `Startup Applications` to make it start automatically upon login. Open Unity Dash and add it as new command.
Of course, make sure you script has executable permissions with `chmod +x /path/to/script.sh`

[image]

To address the issue of chrome deleting cache on startup ( which is undesirable , as mentioned in the comments), use polling with while-loop to wait for chrome to appear.

```
while true; do

    # Wait for chrome window to appear
    while ! pgrep -l 'chrome' ; do : ; sleep 20; done 

    # Now wait for it to disappear
    while pgrep -l 'chrome' ; do : ; sleep 20; done 

    # Once chrome window disappears, delete cache.
    rm -rf ~/.cache/google-chrome/Default/Cache/*
    rm -rf ~/.cache/google-chrome/Default/"Media Cache"/*
    notify-send "CCD" "Cache deleted!"

    # And at this point we restart the whole process again.

done
```

Comment: But if I run that script after startup, it'll see that Chrome is not running, and automatically delete its cache, and then breaks. However, I want it to clean cache everytime I quit Chrome. I know your answer might be right if I slightly edited script, but I have no such scripting knowledge to do that.

Comment: @PKM you already have that knowledge. Use while loop to wait for chrome to appear.  See my updated answer

Comment: I tried to run it, and it deleted cache instantly after executing, despite Chrome was running.

Comment: @PKM typo in the second line. Sorry, I'll correct that. The second while loop had to be without `!` symbol