# ps -e | grep python until some python process runs in the system

Tags: python, cron, process

I want to see if some python process is running. I've set up a python script that updates noip, and a cron runs it every 1 minute, but it takes only 2 seconds to run and finish, so I'd like to know if there's a way to do ps -e | grep python and wait until some python process appear in the screen

Comment: Silly question, but pn what screen, and how exactly is updating noip and pythun running related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is simply to observe is process appears, you can just do this:

```
watch -n1  "ps -ef | grep command | grep -v grep"
```

Personally , I frequently use polling technique with `pgrep` and `while` loop like so:

```
while ! pgrep -f command ; do true; done && echo "Process started"
```

This is a good approach if you want to run additional command if a process appears or disappears.

Test run:

[image]

The way this works is very simple:

- loop runs `pgrep -f command` on each iteration and negates its exit status. Thus if process not found the exit status of `1` negates to `0` , thus keeping the loop running.
- Once the process appears, exit status becomes `0` , it's negated to `1`, causing for loop to terminate and display message with `echo`

This is a pretty universal approach, works with any shell and scripting language. For instance, I used it in a [python script that detects ip change](https://askubuntu.com/a/822796/295286) and [script to run commands when process appears](https://askubuntu.com/a/850804/295286)